# ODP.NET array bind return/OUT param performance

Tags: c#, performance, oracle, odp.net, executenonquery

Some old code that I have uses `OracleDataAdaper.Update(DataSet)`. If I call a test stored proc (that only has input parameters), it takes about 24 seconds for 20,000 rows to be inserted. I needed to improve on that, so I switched to using array binding. With array binding `ExecuteNonQuery()` takes under 3 seconds to insert the same 20,000 rows! That's a huge performance improvement and I also avoid creating expensive DataSets.

However, I got into problems with stored procs that have OUT parameter(s) or functions that return values.

Inserting same 20,000 rows via a stored proc that has an OUT parameter using `OracleDataAdaper.Update(DataSet)` takes about 26 seconds - which is 2 seconds or 8% slower than w/o OUT parameter - not bad. 
But calling same stored proc using array binding causes `ExecuteNonQuery()` to run for 15 minutes! That's 300% slower than w/o OUT parameter!

---

For all OUT/IN OUT/RETURN parameters of variable-length type (i.e. VARCHAR2), I set `OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize` property to `int[numOfRows]` with all values set to max value for type (i.e. 4000 for VARCHAR2).

My test stored proc looks like this (in real life, I could be returning a sequence number):

```
    PROCEDURE INSERT_TEST(
        p_key            VARCHAR2,
        p_id             NUMBER,
        p_dt             DATE,
        p_unique_key OUT VARCHAR2)
      AS
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO T_TEST_DAL(
                      UNIQUE_KEY,
                      NUM_ID,
                      DT_VAL)
        VALUES (
                 p_key,
                 p_id,
                 p_dt)
        RETURNING UNIQUE_KEY
          INTO p_unique_key;
    END INSERT_TEST;
```

---

I use ODP.NET Oracle.DataAccess v4.112.3.0, but I'm pretty sure it's not version-specific.

Has anyone faced similar issues with array-bound OUT parameters? Do I need to set another property for OUT/return parameters to speed this up?

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to improve performance without having to make changes on the database side.  Perhaps using *PLSQLAssociativeArray* would speed things up (I haven't tried yet), but that would require too many changes to pre-existing stored procs.

Comment: Yes, PL/SQL Associative Array speeds it up a lot. Have a look here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401050/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-set-of-values-as-a-parameter-in-an-oracle-sql-statement/20405447#20405447 (sorry code is VB.NET but you should understand it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that ODP.NET does not provide a way to tune "fetch size" for `ExecuteNonQuery()` with array binding. So when a stored proc contains an OUT parameter (or function has RETURN parameter), Oracle sends results of each item back to caller separately.  This results in a lot of networking overhead and significantly slows down the process.

When using `OracleDataAdapter.Update(DataSet)`, the results of the execution are sent in batches, resulting in lower networking overhead.

When there are no OUT params, it's much faster to use `ExecuteNonQuery()` rather than `OracleDataAdapter.Update(DataSet)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the answer with my experience.
Using array binding for Inserts, Updates and Deletes performs wonderfully and ExecutNonQuery correctly returns the number of affected rows.

But because a Merge ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 for the number of affected rows you need to include the Rowcount as an Output parameter, which in turn slows everything down again.

Comment: Please consider reformatting your answer to provide a clear code example with a supporting explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information on how to answer a question.